# The best practice for timeconsuming operations in eclipse rcp view

Tags: database, eclipse, view, rcp

My RCP application contains 5 views which fill contents via database queries.

The problem is that the application start completely depends on database queries. In addition, if underlying db is closed the application start time takes too long.

What is the best practice for eclipse rcp views that use db as content source?
Is using a separate thread for filling views be a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move all your view updating code into an UIJob, then schedule it. User can find the progress of these tasks in the progress view if it is included in your RCP.
In addition, one UIJob takes care one view.

Comment: You want to use a `Job` for all of the db/record processing.  The UIJob is only for posting UI changes to the UI thread, as UIJob will block the UI thread.

Comment: @paul-webster, does this architecture looks logical? 

A background Job handles db access and fills related models 
then view object paints the screen based on this filled model object..

Comment: Yes, that's a common pattern.  Make the UI updating job or runnables small and quick, and do most of the work in a regular `Job`.